# Make a variable final in any given moment (after initialization and eventual code)

Tags: java, variables, immutability, final

Is it possible to make a variable `final` in any given moment?
I would like to decide when its immutable, not just with the first assignment.

It would be perfect, if `null` would not count as an assignment. So if you would initialize it with null, you would still have a wildcard for the first assignment  after some code, not necessarily in the constructor.

Comment: Sounds like a trivial question, but after reading it about 3 times, I still don't really understand what you're asking...

Comment: I am asking for some mechanism or somethign I could be missing. How do u solve this situation?

Comment: @user1352530, What language are you speaking?

Comment: Not my mother tongue. Correct me and you will help me. You are free to edit my question.

Comment: But you did not, because your solely purpose was to freely swear at me. People like you should be apparted from this great community

Comment: @user1352530, How can I possibly edit the question when I do not understand its content?

Comment: You want something like Modifier.isFinal(object, true) but it does not look like that exists http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for you to know, the feature is now proposed in a draft: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/309. It's called dyanmic constant. Check future work section:

- Surfacing the lazy initialization of constants in the Java language

> The value is, therefore, dynamic but, since its value is only set
>   once, it is also constant.

Answer (score 8):

Once you assign a `final` variable, you can never change its value, as stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29):

> A final variable can only be initialized once, either via an
>   initializer or an assignment statement. It does not need to be
>   initialized at the point of declaration: this is called a "blank
>   final" variable.

If you want to have a variable which at a given point in time can be made immutable, what you can do is something like so:

```
...
private boolean isMutable;
private String someString;

public void setMutable(boolean value)
{
    this.isMutable = value;
}

public void setSomeString(String value)
{
    if (this.isMutable)
    {
        this.someString = value;
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 6):

No you cannot. What you can do is encapsulating it withing a method:

```
public boolean setValue(int i)
{
    if(isMutable)
    {
        value = i;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be done when the variable is being declared, therefore it is not possible to make an already declared variable `final`.

Comment: And forcing it someway to be assigned after some code for first time? The problem is the compiler complains with "The final field X cannot be assigned". If I set it to null, it takes it as the first assignment